# Automated text wrapping in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I already tried Google/searching Stack Overflow but did not find a working solution.

I am currently trying to implement a simple chat client. I have a problem with displaying messages though. I currently use a flowchart to which I add Texts and Imageviews depending on the message. Here is what my chat window looks like right now: [image: demo]

This is also how I want my chatwindow to look. In this case I added three Texts containing "This is a. Ssdg", "this is test2" "this is test4" to my flowchart. As "this is test4" would not fit into my window anymore it got correctly wrapped/pushed to the next line, which is exactly what I desire. My problem now is when I have very long text blocks, it looks like this:[image: demo]

The text is longer than my window, but it does not wrap around, it just continues past the visible part. I would like it to line break at the correct place though, so that no text is outside of my window. Using.

```
t.setWrappingWidth(...)
```

Does not work, as my main windows is resizeable, therefore it has no fixed width. Using:

```
t.wrappingWidthProperty.bind(boundingbox.widthProperty())
```

Also does not work as.widthProperty() is 0 when the components are not rendered yet. As a very inefficient solution adding every letter as an individual Text works, but it is kinda slow. I'm searching for an efficient way to line break longer text at the correct place now. It does not necessarily have to adjust dynamically when resizing, just newly added chats should have the correct format.

Comment: What do you use as textblocks? Aint it possible to bind a listener to the main window, where you determine the correct width of every textBlock? Just like anyother node?

Comment: Post a [MCVE] illustrating the problem: pretty much any sensible way I have tried to do something like this it works. What do you mean by "I currently use a flowchart to which I add Texts"? Are you using a [`TextFlow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html)?

Comment: I use the standard Text class. What exactly do you mean by "determine the correct width"? I'm using FlowChart to which I add several instances of  Text and of ImageView

Comment: What is a `FlowChart`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant FlowPane, I was confused as someone called it flowchart somewhere.

Comment: So why not use a `TextFlow` instead?

Answer (score 0):

This might be what are you looking for

https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX

A ChatClient app was made months ago using the above.You can check the code:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/xr3chat/